# redux-observables chain simple epics

Tags: redux-observable

From this issues thread > https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/33#issuecomment-342399904

I've extracted this helper:

```
const forkEpic = (epicFactory, ...actions) => {
    const input$ = Observable.of(...actions); 
    const actions$ = new ActionsObservable(input$);  
    return epicFactory(actions$); 
};
```

My question is, how to insert Epic dependencies on the epicFactory?

Epic dependencies in the form of https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/InjectingDependenciesIntoEpics.html

The main idea behind is (as discussesd un the issue) is chaining epics

The injected dependencies are undefined, and as said on this question, passing the dependencies director does not solve the issue. (https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/33#issuecomment-342399904)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record the answer > https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/issues/33#issuecomment-342786804